# Why there spread operator (...) is use in the .pyi file in the function definition?

Tags: python, optparse, pyi

I often encounter spread (...)  in the source code of many programs. I google about it but I did not find any relevant answer. I am wondering why spread operator are use in the file. Here is the example.

```
class HelpFormatter:
    def __init__(self, indent_increment: int, max_help_position: int, width: Optional[int], short_first: int) -> None: ...
    def _format__Text(self, _Text: _Text) -> _Text: ...
    def dedent(self) -> None: ...
    def expand_default(self, option: Option) -> _Text: ...
    def format_description(self, description: _Text) -> _Text: ...
    def format_epilog(self, epilog: _Text) -> _Text: ...
    def format_heading(self, heading: Any) -> _Text: ...
    def format_option(self, option: OptionParser) -> _Text: ...
    def format_option_strings(self, option: OptionParser) -> Any: ...
    def format_usage(self, usage: Any) -> _Text: ...
    def indent(self) -> None: ...
    def set_long_opt_delimiter(self, delim: _Text) -> None: ...
    def set_parser(self, parser: OptionParser) -> None: ...
    def set_short_opt_delimiter(self, delim: _Text) -> None: ...
    def store_option_strings(self, parser: OptionParser) -> None: ...
```

What is the purpose of pyi file and why spread operator is used?

Here is image how code look like
[image]

Comment: See that *where*? It's not in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/37440eef7f9a0c27e13fc9ce0850574bb00688b0/Lib/optparse.py#L161, for example.

Comment: Can you show a link to where you found this?

Comment: That's not the actual class definition.  That appears to be some sort of "stub file" that just gives names & types for the parameters and return values of the methods, probably for the benefit of the IDE you're using.

Comment: They look like ellipsis...

Comment: Where do you see such examples?

Comment: The filename is optparse.pyi

Comment: I attach the image too,  file is .pyi, not .py

Comment: I am using vscode

Comment: here is the ref https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/blob/master/src/Analysis/Ast/Impl/Typeshed/stdlib/2and3/optparse.pyi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it's kinda "interface" realization. It's equal to:

```
def func():
    pass
```